# some pointer declarations not colored

Tags: terminal-emacs, colors, c

`macs -nw` fails to color code certain declarations of pointer arrays seemingly depending on the structure being pointed to. For example: `SomeStruct *one[4]` is all white (I have dark background), but `OtherStruct *two[4]` has the correct color scheme (green type, yellow name). (note `SomeStruct one[4]` has correct color scheme)

Both structures are defined and included from the same file, and everything compiles and runs as expected, but the coloring is just inconsistent, which is really annoying from a UI perspective for someone with OCD :)

Comment: "`[e]macs -nw` fails to color" - do you mean that when running in graphical it's coloured correctly?

Comment: Can you produce a minimally reproducible code sample?